# How to use jalali (persian) calendar in adminisration of Virtuemart 2.x, joomla

Tags: joomla, calendar, joomla2.5, virtuemart, persian

I need Jalali (persian) calendar in admin of virtuemart.

Please guide me.

Virtuemart 2.x
Joomla 2.5.x

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @ccpl, unfortunately Joomla Q&A StackExchange is not so popular and I think many users do know it. I've send this question on Joomla Q&A too. This is the [link] (http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5155/how-to-use-jalali-persian-calendar-in-administration-of-virtuemart)

Comment: Given that the core developers of both Joomla and Virtuemart answer questions on Joomla SE I have to disagree. Have you tried the Virtuemart forums?

Comment: No I did not use Virtemart forums yet, I think I should use it now.